# Play: Eclipse not resolving PlayEbean Package

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I have a Play Framework project that includes the Ebean lib in plugins.sbt:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

And also enables it in build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
```

I then run `activator eclipse` and the play-ebean jar is in the project.  I then import the package into a class:

```
import play.db.ebean.model;
```

And Play itself seems content with it, however, Eclipse is marking it as an unresolved dependency.

Any tips on what I am missing in my Eclipse config?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in to the `build.sbt` next settings:

```
// Eclipse settings

// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files,
// so that generated .scala or .class files for views and routes are present
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)

// Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java

// Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)

// End of eclipse settings
```

That helped me